# How to change a color of table data in according to date

Tags: php, html

how can I change a color of a table data () in according to date ?

e.g i have a simple calendar which is created in   and each day is in other table data () so if we have 24 january, the previous days in table data should have a background-color:red; and the next days including 24 january should have a background-color:grey;

It's possible to do it in php ?

Comment: We need to see what you have done so far.

Comment: Of course it is possible to do in PHP, but you have to post some code if you want our help.

Comment: [http://pastebin.com/BjpxUgP2](http://pastebin.com/BjpxUgP2) - I think it is all code without unnecessary things

Answer (score 0):

Use `date('j')` to figure out current day number and in the for loop on 24. - 29. row you can compare day number to current day number and set `<td style="background-color: ...">` to what you want. Or better attitude is to make two classes, `.calendar-day-past` and `.calendar-day-future`, and set the `background-color` property to them.

Comment: And one more advice - should not be the 31st row within the for loop too?